# How to add a very simple controller to a set of differential equations

Tags: matlab, controls, ode, differential-equations, matlab-compiler

I have a very complicated set of differential equations with several time dependent variables. I have found a simplification of my code online, it's here;
It's in two sections. First

```
`t_values=linspace(0,10,101); 
 initial_cond=[1 ; 0 ; 0];  
 [tv,Yv]=ode45('simplemodel',t_values,initial_cond);
 plot(tv,Yv(:,1),'+',tv,Yv(:,2),'x',tv,Yv(:,3),'o');
 legend('y1','y2','y3');`
```

Then another

```
function Dy = simplemodel(t,y)

Dy=[ a(t)*y(1)+b(t)*y(2); ...
-a(t)*y(3)+b(t)*y(1); ...
 a(t)*y(2)] ;
 end

function fa=a(t);
    fa=cos(t); % or place whatever you want to place for a(t)..
end

function fb=b(t);
  fb=sin(t) % or place whatever you want to place for b(t)..
end
```

I have a problem however, that I want to try to add a PID controller to my `a(t)` term.. I have tried to do first add a "proportional term" by changing the `fb=sin(t)` line to `fb=-K*y(2)+d+K*int(y(2))+K*diff(y(2))`, where `K` and `d` are constants. When I substitute this `fb` line for the one in the code, I get errors. Any ideas guys? Thank you very much

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to contain a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi @Wrzlpmft Is my example not complete and minimal. The code provided also works, I just need it extending. Thanks :)

Comment: *The code provided also works* – Exactly. Show us what you tried and doesn’t work.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ah Ok I see. I have modified the last paragraph to show the line of code I enter and where my problem is. I hope this helps :)

Comment: What do you expect that `int(y(2))` and `diff(y(2))` should do to this scalar value? Note also that there is no `y` in the scope of the function `b`.

Comment: @LutzL I was hoping they would act as a PID controller

Comment: By its names I assume that you expect some integration and differentiation to happen. Do you think that your syntax is conform with the documentation of these functions? `int` is an operator on symbolic expressions, this is a completely different level.

Comment: @LutzL I see. How would you suggest I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You want to go from a system that is described by

```
function Dy = simplemodel(t,y)
  a = cos(t)
  b = sin(t)
  Dy=[ a*y(1)+b*y(2); ...
      -a*y(3)+b*y(1); ...
       a*y(2)] ;
 end
```

to something that has

```
  b = -K*y(2)+d+K*Iy2+K*Dy2
```

where `Dy2` is the derivative and `Iy2` the anti-derivative of the second component. The first problem is that

```
Dy(2) = -a*y(3)+b*y(1)
```

depends itself on `b`, which depends on `Dy(2)` so that you get some feed-back resp. a dependency circle that you have to solve. This can be done by solving

```
Dy(2) = -a*y(3)+(b1+K*Dy(2))*y(1);
```

for `Dy(2)`. `b1` contains all the other parts of `b`, so that in total the circle is solved as

```
b1 = -K*y(2)+d+K*Iy2
Dy(2) = (-a*y(3) + b1*y(1))/(1-K*y(1))
b = b1+K*Dy(2);
```

This still contains the as-of-yet unaddressed anti-derivative value. In other words, we need a function whose derivative is `y(2)`. As such a function is not present in the system, we have to add an extra component to it,

```
function Dy = simplemodel(t,y)
  a = cos(t)
  Dy(4) = y(2) % y(4) = integral(y(2))
  b1 = -K*y(2)+d+K*y(4) % missing +K*Dy(2)
  Dy(2) = (-a*y(3) + b1*y(1))/(1-K*y(1))
  b2 = K*Dy(2); 
  b = b1+b2;
  Dy(1) = a*y(1)+b*y(2)
  Dy(3) = a*y(2)
end
```

You will still need some initial value for the anti-derivative, most likely it will be `0` if the system is thought of being switched on after a state of rest.

Comment: Thank you so much for this @LutzL. After a couple of hours playing I am however having problem running this exact example? All I have done is added values for K and d above where a is defined, and added a fourth "0" for my initial condition. I get "Error using odearguments (line 91)
SIMPLEMODEL must return a column vector." I have tried altering the initial condition to a coloum and row vector to no avail. Does the code posted work for you?

Comment: You will need to add some initial declaration like `Dy=zeros_like(y)`. I have no matlab available to test the syntax.